# What controls `invalid indirect expansion` reporting in bash?

Tags: bash

I had been using indirect expansion and relying on the result being a null string when the variable is unset:

```
$ $SHELL --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
$ unset var
$ echo "${!var}"

$
```

but on a new Linux box that fails with `invalid indirect expansion`:

```
$ $SHELL --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ unset var
$ echo "${!var}"
-bash: var: invalid indirect expansion
$
```

Obviously I can change my code to work both places but so far I haven't been able to figure out the exact difference between the 2 systems that's causing the failure on 1 but not the other and I want to know what that difference is to best address this issue and anything similar that comes up in future.

If it's just the change in bash version, I can't find any release notes or anything indicating that. If it's some option being set on one, I can't find that either (it's not `set -u` for example). FWIW here's the difference in `shopt` output between the machine that's failing (second column) and the one that isn't (third column):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{ARGIND++} {a[$1,ARGIND]=$2; b[$1]} END{for (var in b) if (a[var,1] != a[var,2]) print var, a[var,1], a[var,2]}' bad good | column -t
autocd              off
compat32            off
localvar_unset      off
lastpipe            off
localvar_inherit    off
complete_fullquote  on
assoc_expand_once   off
checkwinsize        on   off
globasciiranges     on
compat40            off
compat41            off
compat42            off
inherit_errexit     off
compat43            off
compat44            off
checkjobs           off
expand_aliases      on   off
globstar            off
progcomp_alias      off
dirspell            off
direxpand           off
login_shell         on   off
```

Anyone know exactly why I see the failure on one Unix box but not the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's changed for 5.0-alpha, the [`CHANGES` file in the Bash source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-5.1&id=8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581#n1003) has this entry:

```
This document details the changes between this version, bash-5.0-alpha, and
the previous version, bash-4.4-release.
[...]

y. If indirect expansion attempts to indirectly reference through an unset
   variable, report an error.
```

Here's a post about that from the author on the mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-11/msg00165.html

> It's pretty clear that indirect expansion that attempts to reference
> through an unset variable or a variable whose value is null should be an
> error. Bash-4.3 didn't have the greatest error checking, and bash-4.4
> catches the null value case.  I'll fix it to catch the unset variable
> case, too.

Indeed with Bash 4.4 the case with an empty value errors:

```
$ ./bash4.4 -c 'var=; echo ${!var}'
./bash4.4: : bad substitution
```

Comment: @EdMorton, added the link.

Comment: @EdMorton, found it on the mailing list too

Comment: Perfect, thanks!